# How do I determine NodeTree overhead in a .blend file?

Tags: node-editor, blend-files

Since we have the ability to save a NodeTree into the deault .blend file I'm wondering if there are any guidelines or ceilings that need to be observed before I ramp up and save lots of NoteTrees into the default file.  I find myself using some of the bwide stuff quite a bit and am thinking of dropping into the startup file but I don't want to go to the trouble of doing this if it might cause performance or other issues down the road.

Thanks for any guidance on this

@lan

Comment: If you can't tell the overhead from simply opening the two, does it even matter?

Answer (score 2):

This should not affect anything significantly. I have already added a few of my own nodegroups and a couple node groups from the b°wide nodepack to my startup.blend and have noticed no side effects.

Nodegroups don't really affect performance (unless they are being used), the biggest thing would be file size (which you probably don't have to worry about, because they don't take up much space).